# django not saving CharField

Tags: python, mysql, django

i got model in my django app with following code

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password_salt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField()

    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
    last_online = models.DateTimeField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

after executing this block of code in my view "password_salt" field is not saving data

```
salt = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(100))
work_user = User.objects.create(
    username = str('some' + request_parsed['moresome']),
    password = md5('some hashing method' + salt),
    password_salt = salt,
    balance = 0,
    last_update = datetime.datetime.now(),
    last_online = datetime.datetime.now(),
    date_created = datetime.datetime.now()
    )
```

while im trying to create this object mannualy with django admin site its works perfeclty fine.

P.S. i'm not using django built-in user because its just datauser and not actuall user.

Comment: Whats the difference between a data user and actual user? I'm fairly new to Django, but I've created a blog with it. I am using the Django User model and its working as I hoped it would. I like that it has function decorator to help restrict access to certain views by just adding @login_required and that it handles sessions.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are rolling your own User model instead of using the built in one? Also md5 hashing of passwords probably isn't something you want to do - it's not secure and easy to brute-force.

Comment: @solarissmoke im absolutely sure - because its now web-page project. its just web-server with db. about md5 - its not a permanent solution. its fast and cheap enough. its all that i can ask for this moment

Comment: @Sync for youre solution - built-in user is perfectly fine and in 99% nobody needs a custom user. even i can use it, but its have way too much redundant fields and logic.

Comment: @YegorShatov Cool, it'll be an interesting experience of creating your own user + session model. Good luck with it!

Comment: @Sync i dont need session, thats why im not using default user. Thanks!